# Is there any way to create xamarin mobile applications on linux?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I know this is very old question? but still i am looking for an answer. Is xamarin available for linux or not? If it is not available is there any alternate solution?

I heard about mono development. Shall I use mono development for xamarin on linux. If yes, share with details. It'll be very helpfull.

Comment: why this question is  downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

The `Xamarin.Android` framework does build on linux and via the cross-platform MSBuild does allow you to compile `Xamarin.Android`-based projects.

Unlike Windows and MacOS, it is **not an officially supported production platform**, you are on your own in terms of setup, environment, bugs, etc.. and also you are on your own in regards to Development UI/IDEs.

See the GitHub repo for details in the readme:

Re: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android